Issues with UI Grid not Properly Rendering after ng-show
I am swapping the UI grid in and out using ng-show so when I show this grid this is the result I am seeing inside of angularjs 1.8.3. The header names and proper columns do not appear until I change the screen size. I have tried to do many of the different refresh methods documented here but nothing seems to work. Anyone come across a similar issue and know of a solution?

